# How can Word fill up each line with as many footnotes as each line can fit?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I command Word to footnote like  at the bottom of the scan? MI don't know if this scan were formatted in Word.

My colors highlight lines with 1, 2 or 3 footnotes, but Word only allows you to pick the same number of footnotes per line. It's obviously too unproductive  to eyeball and pick how many footnotes ought be in each line, to fill up each line without wasting space.

[image]

This is  Herring's [*Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (8 edn, 2018)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/criminal-law-9780198811817?cc=ca&lang=en&). p 180.

Comment: What are you actually asking? It's really not clear. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: That wouldn't have been formatted in Word.  In Word, each footnote starts on a separate paragraph, and you can't delete the paragraph mark at end to run them on to have multiple footnotes on same line.

Comment: @Tanya Thanks. Any idea on what software was used to format?